# How to call functions from other dynamically created files | Python

Tags: tkinter, python-import

I have a python program

> main.py

and I import all dynamically created files from a folder using this function:

```
def loadImports(path):
files = os.listdir(path)
imps = []

for i in range(len(files)):
    name = files[i].split('.')
    if len(name) > 1:
        if name[1] == 'py' and name[0] != '__init__':
           name = name[0]
           imps.append(name)

file = open(path+'__init__.py','w')

toWrite = '__all__ = '+str(imps)

file.write(toWrite)
file.close()

loadImports('MyDIR/')
from MyDIR import *
```

there are few scripts:

```
 first.py
 second.py
 third.py
```

every scripts has a function in it:

```
def play():
    pass
```

It works perfectly when I call it from main.py like this:

```
    def myCall(self):
        first.play()

    self.myCall()
```

But I have an tkinter comboBox from which I want to select the name of the script, for example:

> first

and

call it like this:

```
    def myCall(self):
        name = self.myComboBox.get()
        name.play()

    self.myCall()
```

but then there is an error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "PATH/main.py", line 1183, in myCall
>       name.play() 
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'play'

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()`, but first read about the dangers: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

```
eval('{}.play()'.format(name))
```

The string results in: `first.play()` (if name=='first' obviously...)  and then `eval` runs it.

**Update**

Thought of maybe a better way, not using `eval`:

Create a dict with associations between loaded module names and references to the modules.

```
""" Module first.py contains:
def play(recording):
    print('Playing:', recording)
"""

import first

first.play('Testing')           # Testing that it works

module_dict = {'first': first}  # Creating a dict with associations between
                                # names and module references

module = module_dict.get('first', None) # Get reference from name
                                        # Returns None if no module found

if module: module.play('For real') # Use function from named module if not None
```

Comment: But how does it add another modules to dict, when they are created?

Comment: You will have to do that explicitly in each case; for example `import second` should be followed by `module_dict['second'] = second`

Comment: yeah, but these modules will be created by users dynamically. Anyway, I used 'eval' and made it like they can't write any '_' there, so it shouldn't make any harm, right? What else I can do there to make it even more safe?

Comment: As long as you're aware of the risks.

Comment: I asked what can I do to make it more safe? Maybe exclude some more characters?

Comment: Well, you might want to restrict expressiont that are to be eveluated to a fixed structure, for example `module.function(arg)` or whatever you might want to make available to the users. I don't have the knowledge on how to parse this structure with regexp, but you could also do it by examining the string. Other than that I have not much information. Google "dangers with eval" and you might find something.